# how to get iframe of a website that scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i have been working on a project where i have to get an iframe of a website but when i got the iframe it all got messed
This is the website link

http://carclub.apexfour.com/

And this is what coded

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://carclub.apexfour.com/" width="1349" height="3859.27"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by messed? What is the problem? It's loading perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

"DOCTYPE" is missing in your page and reduce iframe height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://carclub.apexfour.com/" width="1349" 
    height="1200"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard coded `width` and `height` are conflicting with the CSS inside the `iframe`, stretching the iframe like that is creating large empty spaces. When you say:

> "it all got messed up"

I am assuming you are talking about the styles.

Try something like this to get it started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      height: 100%;
    }
    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://carclub.apexfour.com/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```